# fail to start genomotion2.2.2 android devices with virtualbox4.2 in ubuntu12.04

Tags: android, virtualbox, ubuntu-12.04, genymotion

I have lost 2days of my life in this problem;

I want to use genomotion in ubuntu12.04(Installed in my VMWare), my environments:

Windows7(x64) => VMWareV8.0.3 (Bridged Network, Ubuntu12.04)
Then, I installed VirtualBox4.2 in Ubuntu && Genymotion(2.2)

After problems soloved 1 by 1, I was stucked by the launchment of Android Devices (Downloaded from Genomotion Cloud)

```
➜  genymotion sudo ./genymotion
Logging activities to file: /home/ganiks/.Genymobile/genymotion.log
Logging activities to file: /home/ganiks/.Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed/Google Nexus 7 - 4.4.4 - API 19 - 800x1280/genymotion-player.log
OpenGL connected to 192.168.56.101:25000
Port 22468 will be used for OpenGL data connections
PING timed out
Failed to connect to VM (TcpStream) for main host connection, IP:Port=192.168.56.101:25000!!!
Failed to connect to VM (TcpStream) for main host connection, IP:Port=192.168.56.101:25000!!!
Failed to connect to VM (TcpStream) for main host connection, IP:Port=192.168.56.101:25000!!!
Failed to connect to VM (TcpStream) for main host connection, IP:Port=192.168.56.101:25000!!!
Failed to connect to VM (TcpStream) for main host connection, IP:Port=192.168.56.101:25000!!!
Failed to connect to VM (TcpStream) for main host connection, IP:Port=192.168.56.101:25000!!!
Failed to connect to VM (TcpStream) for main host connection, IP:Port=192.168.56.101:25000!!!
Failed to connect to VM (TcpStream) for main host connection, IP:Port=192.168.56.101:25000!!!
Failed to connect to VM (TcpStream) for main host connection, IP:Port=192.168.56.101:25000!!!
```

I have 4 screenshots here, I guess my problem is related to the  Android Device cannot lanch correctly, then 192.168.56.101's port 25000 is not reachable.
(ping 192.168.56.101 is ok)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Could anybody give me some advice or other solutinos ?

Thanks in advance ~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Genymotion cannot work inside a virtual machine. See https://www.genymotion.com/help/desktop/faq/#virtual-machine-start-impossible for more details.